# What conditions on the coefficient category allow one to check isomorphisms for sheaves on stalks?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category which admits small limits and small filtered colimits.
For a topological space $X$,
one can define $\operatorname{Sh}(X;\mathscr{C})$ to be the subcategory of $\operatorname{PSh}(X;\mathscr{C}) = \operatorname{Fun}(\operatorname{Op}_X^{op},\mathscr{C})$
generated by objects $F$ which satisfy the condition
$\Gamma(U;F) \cong \lim \Gamma(U_i;F)$ where $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of U.

Now assume there is a morphism $f: F\rightarrow G$ such that on each stalk $f_x$ is
an isomorphism.
What are the known conditions on $\mathscr{C}$ which will imply $f$ an isomorphism in this situation?
In other words, what are the known conditions on $\mathscr{C}$ that will make the functor
$I: \operatorname{Sh}(X;\mathscr{C}) \rightarrow \prod_{x \in X} \mathscr{C}$
which is given by $I(F) = (F_x)_{x \in X}$ conservative?

Comment: It suffices that there exist a conservative functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that preserves limits and filtered colimits. However, personally, I think it is in the first place inappropriate to even consider categories of sheaves for which this theorem is not true.

Comment: Does this holds when $\mathscr{C} = \operatorname{Cat}$ the category of all small categories and some variant of it? (I do not care of the 2-categorical structure of $\operatorname{Cat}$ for now.)

Comment: Yes. But that is not the right approach to defining sheaves (or, rather, stacks) of categories.